# Is it possible to read the last line of STDOUT from an open process?

Tags: ruby, io, pipe

I am using Stockfish to analyze a chess position, but the specific context isn't that important.  I want to read the output from the program in real-time without having to wait until the process is finished.  In particular I want to read the last or last few lines.  Current I have:

```
require 'pty'

master, slave = PTY.open
read, write = IO.pipe
pid = spawn("stockfish", :in=>read, :out=>slave)
calculating=0 
slave.close
read.close

write.puts('uci')
write.puts("setoption name Threads value 1")
write.puts("position fen rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR")
write.puts('go infinite')

while calculating<10    
    sleep(1)
    master.each do |line|
        puts line
    end     
    calculating+=1      
end

write.puts('quit')
write.close

puts "done"
```

The problem with this is that the program isn't seeing an EOF marker until all 10 loops are finished so it's getting stuck in the `master.each` line block indefinitely.  I can read the next line from the beginning one at a time with `master.gets`, but how would I read the last line instead?

Comment: The problem might be I/O buffering. If stockfish output is buffered, then you will see it only if buffer is written, if buffer is flushed or if stockfish terminates. Try to disable output buffering (must be done inside stockfish), if possible.

Comment: The ruby module PTY takes care of that.  It creates a pseudo shell that tricks stockfish into thinking that I'm running everything directly from the shell

Comment: @kempchee I didn't know about the PTY module.  Nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution now:

```
fen="rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR"
overseer=fork do
  require 'pty'
  master, slave = PTY.open
  read, write = IO.pipe
  pid = spawn("stockfish", :in=>read, :out=>slave)
  slave.close
  read.close
  write.puts('uci')
  write.puts("setoption name Threads value 4")
  write.puts("position fen #{fen}")
  write.puts('go infinite')

  loop do
   puts master.gets     
  end   

end

if $stdin.gets
  Process.kill("KILL",overseer)
end
```

This will print out a stream of stream until the user kills it.